# Create new text file using level brackets

Tags: notepad++

I am having a text file that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible with `notepad++` to extract all that bracket levels to new files with the names of the text inside the brackets, but not like driving / ambulance guide but driving_ambulanceguide.tag

That would be great for what I need to do! :)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing yet, because I am absolutely clueless.. I googled a little bit and it seems to work with linux and awk, but I don't know anything about it. My Linux skills are very, very limited

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239). And add expected result. What are the rules to transform `[driving / ambulance guide]` into `driving_ambulanceguide.tag`?